# How to set constraints in IB using ctrl-drag if the size of my subview is the same as its superview?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I've added a subview to one of my view-controllers in IB. Its size is the same as the view-controller's size and I want it to be that way. The only problem is that now I can't use ctrl-drag with mouse to set some of the constraints with reference to its superview. Is there a way I can have a subview which fills its entire superview and still set constraints **using ctrl-drag** with reference to that superview.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you cannot drag to the superview as it's full of subview and cannot be selected by drag? If so, you can control-drag to the view in the left column list.

Comment: @user3349433 Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for. Make it your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control-drag to the view in the left column list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *pin* button in lower right corner of edit view.

1. Click *pin* button.
2. Select all constraints (make sure constant value is set to 0).
3. Accept constraints.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I was particularly looking for a way to use ctrl-drag to set a constraint.